# What am I doing wrong

Tags: php, explode, server-variables

I have been struggling with this for a week or two now, and I just cant seem to resolve it.  Here is my Script:

```
<?php
$Domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$paryDomain = explode(".",$Domain);
$Array = count($paryDomain);
$RootDomain = "";
$G_SYSTEMID = "";

if ($Array == "1")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}    
elseif ($Array == "2")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[1].'.'.$paryDomain[2];
}

if ($RootDomain == "storeboard.com")
{
    $G_SYSTEMID = 1;
}
elseif ($RootDomain == "dcwn.org")
{
    $G_SYSTEMID = 2;
}

echo $G_SYSTEMID;
echo "------------";

?>
```

Why do I get no result at the end either 1 or 2..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Neojakey

Comment: I would say the obvious cause is that $RootDomain is neither of the strings you compare it too... Maybe you can echo it and see what the actual value is...?

Comment: Start echoing out variables at various points throughout the logic and see where they start not being what you're expecting.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong" <- not using an appropriate title.

Comment: Maybe you should check as INTEGER not as STRING... `$Array == "1"` is string due to `$Array == 1` is INTEGER. If you `count($var);` you will get result as INTEGER.

Comment: Yes do the test as an integer and dump the variables.

Comment: Use var_dump($paryDomain) to see the content of your explode operation, that could help. Other thing, try using strcmp to compare strings http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: Some one is on a down voting frenzy today lol

Comment: Many thanks for all your help, and my apologies for the inappropriate title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($Array == 1)
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0]; 
}    
elseif ($Array == 2)
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}    
elseif ($Array == 3)
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[1].'.'.$paryDomain[2];
} else {
    //to debug the possible cause 
    $G_SYSTEMID = 'Array length was equal to '.$Array;
    $RootDomain = false;
}
```

You had your array count not matching the pointers you were using this should help. You were also checking for strings instead of integers...

Comment: I made this change an still got no output from the script.. Any other suggestions..?

Comment: @neojakey see edit :) you had to use count function to count array length and you had the array pointer numbers incorrect :) arrays start at `0`

Comment: @neojakey third edit ive added an extra if to take into account all options

Comment: +1 Dave that is true, I also explained it in detail

Answer (score 1):

```
$Array = count($paryDomain);
if ($Array == "1")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}
```

if `$Array` contains one element then `$paryDomain[1]` is not exist, or the array must contain only one element.

for whose that says about $Array that is integer:

```
$Array = 1;
var_dump(($Array == "1"));
var_dump(($Array == "2"));

bool(true) 

bool(false)
```

WHAT IS WRONGS IS:
Your server name if any ((www.)?example.com):

```
if ($Array == "1")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}    
elseif ($Array == "2")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[1].'.'.$paryDomain[2];
}
```

Because
    `$paryDomain = explode(".",$Domain);` at least contains two element, then, $Array is never equals to one, only in one cases, when SERVER_NAME is one word!

Solution:

```
if ($Array == "2")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}    
elseif ($Array == "3")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[1].'.'.$paryDomain[2];
}else{

}

if ($RootDomain == "storeboard.com")
{
    $G_SYSTEMID = 1;
}
elseif ($RootDomain == "dcwn.org")
{
    $G_SYSTEMID = 2;
}else{
//in case when none of above cases true
    $G_SYSTEMID = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to show you an easier way to do this. It will support domains with unlimited sub-domains as it grabs the last two parts always:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], ".") !== false) {
    preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z]+)$/i', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $item);
    $RootDomain = $item['domain'];
} else {
    $RootDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

switch ($RootDomain)
{
    case 'storeboard.com':
        $G_SYSTEMID = 1;
        break;
    case 'dcwn.org':
        $G_SYSTEMID = 2;
        break;
    default:
        $G_SYSTEMID = '';
        break;
}

echo $G_SYSTEMID;
```

Comment: @Baba should `\.[a-z\.]{2,6})` be changed to `\.[a-z]+)`? I think the period is a typo right? Also this would limit the TLD to 2-6 chars, but ICANN has opened up the [purchase](http://www.techspot.com/news/47031-icann-selling-custom-top-level-domains-for-185000.html) of TLDs so we can have domains like mysite.somefancytld in the future.

Comment: `ICANN selling custom top-level domains for $185,000` wow .. thanks for the information .... you can change it

Answer (score 0):

First echo your $Domain

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Then print_r your $paryDomain

```
print_r($paryDomain);
```

And if these are correct, echo your count()

```
echo count(explode(".",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$G_SYSTEMID = strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'storeboard.com') ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: eh, still like my way better :)

Comment: Yeah if you don't care about checking for the other domain `dcwn.org`...

Comment: i only see two options, and even if there were more, it wouldn't be a big deal to add a line for each and default with 0. It's still less writing than using a switch or otherwise.

Comment: and btw, if you are going to manipulate the server name and explode it into an array, you should probably make sure there is a period in the server name before you attempt to split it. ie. localhost

Comment: good, i'm glad you agree ;)

Comment: nick, _Sometimes incompetence is useful. It helps you keep an open mind._ **Roberto Cavalli**

Comment: and thanks for welcoming me to the community :)